# Should we write api’s specific or generic?

Tags: java, sql, api, rest

**Before starting you should be confident that the sql query below is sql injection proof.**

Let’s say we’re writing api that returns customers by filtering the given customer object.

customer object would be like

```
class Customer{
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String surname;
 //etc.

}

and sql to execute would be like : 

select * from customers 
<where> 
 <if test=“obj.id != null”> id = #{obj.id} and </if>
 <if test=“obj.name != null”> name = #{obj. name} and </if>
 <if test=“obj.surname != null”> surname = #{obj. surname} and </if>
<where>
```

thus we can return either all customers or any any number of customers according to the given parameters

of course this service is highly exploitable but by doing so we pass the business logic to the caller which means caller should be certain of its request.

is something like that a good idea or we should write multiple rest services that returns

- one customer by given id
- customer list by given name
- customer list by given surname
- customer list by both given name & surname

Comment: I suppose the string interpolation/templating framework you've shown (`<if ...`) is not SQL-aware right? So is the question "is allowing SQL injection a good idea?" Should go without saying, but no. Also, what if, for example, the `id` is specified, but no others? You've got a dangling `and` condition

Comment: that’s mybatis automatically disables sql injection in this case.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you think it's "highly exploitable"

Comment: right i’ve just updated the question but to sum up i meant that we could use this service for multiple reasons as i’ve just stated.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would say an api shouldn't give visibility of the underlying structures. The caller shouldn't care where or how the data are stored.

In the generic case you might have an api with N possible parameters and N possible conditions in the `where` clause. That's ok.

What really needs to be done in this case with the backend architecture is **be careful not to pass request parameters directly to the logic that builds the query** without first validating, sanitizing and using prepared statements.